# Arbitrary Sender (ex: Arduino) + Chromecast

Tags: chromecast

I'm trying to create a device that lets me specify youtube videos for playback via chromecast from an arbitrary client. In my case, the client is CURL running on Arduino.

I've hit a wall pretty early. I see the SDK is available for client 'senders' on Android, iOS, and Chrome Apps. However, is there any published spec (or has anyone reverse engineered) how to request media from the youtube listener itself?

I can't seem to send ad-hoc requests to chromecast requesting a YouTube video.  Before attempting the next step: fireup wireshark and see if I can reverse engineer how the youtube app on my phone is accomplishing this, I was hoping the community might be able to help.

I found an example that doesn't appear to work anymore (possibly due to a newer FW on my chromecast device, this project is >3mo old)

https://github.com/entertailion/ChromeCast-Arduino

So, in my case, I'm trying both of the following URLs:

```
http://10.0.1.2:8008/apps/YouTube

http://10.0.1.2:8008/connection/YouTube
```

Sending this:

```
POST /apps/YouTube HTTP/1.1
Host: www.arduino.cc
User-Agent: arduino-ethernet
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 12

v=GWXLPu8Ky9k
```

But I just get back 404 errors or content-length: 0 responses and chromecast doesn't appear to do anything different (remains on youtube splashscreen or homescreen).

So, with all of this said, any ideas on how I can communicate directly (from client to Chromecast via HTTP POST) with the youtube receiver?

Answer (score 0):

use POST and `v=` switch, like

```
curl --data "v=nLd6h5td8G4" http://ip.of.your.chromecast:8008/apps/YouTube
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Bas, but as you can see from my "Sending this" in the original question, I am using HTTP POST and have provided the v= parameter...